# Passar dados entre duas páginas HTML (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, html, html5, google

Estou tentando passar a variável 'id' da página 'a.hmtl' para 'b.html'. O conteúdo dessa var vem da página 'código.gs' como mostra abaixo:

código.gs

```
function dados(){
var id = 1;

return id;
}
```

Em seguida, eu resgato essa variável e mostro ela no código a.html:

a.html

```html
<?
var id = dados();
?>

<h1><?= id ?></h1>

<a href="b.html">Ir para B</a>
```

Clicando no link 'Ir para B', o sistema direciona o usuário para a página b.html. Preciso resgatar o mesmo valor da variável 'id' da página a.html na b.html.
Obs.: Com algumas pesquisas, vi que existe uma forma de passar a variável via cache, mas quando tentei usar em meu código, não funcionou.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Evite colocar saudações. Seja formal e impessoal esse é site técnico cujo o publico é técnico e problemas e soluções devem alçar o escopo técnico.